# Unable to load JPEG CMKY image in Python

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, jpeg

I'm trying to open with Python a series of images like this example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ue2VfK-I5uQjt0PcQ9ZgZY3dHrSPi7eM/view?usp=sharing.

I could open them using MatLab, but I want to open them with python.

Trying to open them with ImageJ, I knew that the are JPEG in CMYK format

I used this code in Phython (3.8.5), using matplotlib (3.3.4):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mi_img='1.jpg';
I=plt.imread(mi_img)
```

And I got this error:

```
File "C:\Users\bbarbes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2246, in imread
return matplotlib.image.imread(fname, format)

File "C:\Users\bbarbes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 1496, in imread
    with img_open(fname) as image:

  File "C:\Users\bbarbes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2967, in open
    raise UnidentifiedImageError(

UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'C:/Users/bbarbes/OneDrive - unav.es/0_programas/cine/raw/1.jpg'
```

I tryed with opencv (4.0.1): this code:

```py
import cv2
I = cv2.imread(mi_img,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
cv2.imshow('image',I)
```

An I got this error:

```
OpenCV(4.0.1) C:\ci\opencv-suite_1573470242804\work\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:352: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

And, also, I found that `I` was `NoneType object`

If it helps, used imghdr to check the image, with:

```
import imghdr
imghdr.what(mi_img)
```

and the answer was
`'jpeg'`.

Does anyone know how to load this image in Python?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: I wasn't able to open the image using the Win10 Photos app, is that normal?

Comment: Same here, unable to open the image from the given link.

Comment: Most programs can't read CMYK JPEG files. ImageMagick is one that can, though, so you could use ImageMagick to convert the CMYK images to RGB before having Python read them. Best to save them in a lossless format like PNG at that point to avoid further JPEG compression.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Indeed, it is a 'strange' format: 16bit gray-scale jpeg CMKY. I only could open it using MatLab. I work in medicine, and a program storages the images in that format, and they are a lot of images. So convert them one by one is a time consuming solution.

Comment: You could use Python Wand, which relies upon ImageMagick.

Comment: thanks, fmw42. I'll try

Comment: Nothing. I used ImageMagick Version: ImageMagick 7.0.11-12 Q16 x64 2021-05-09 and tried `convert 1.jpg 1.png' but I got `convert: Unsupported JPEG process: SOF type 0xc3 `1.jpg' @ error/jpeg.c/JPEGErrorHandler/346.`